# Need to get data from one sheet according to which name is a selected and print out all the information

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have a main sheet called DPS, and all the information is in this one sheet. Lets say I have someone called Rob, and on the Main DPS Sheet it is showing that Rob has completed 4 jobs, i need all the jobs that he has completed with descriptions on a different sheet.

I have tried to use a Macro, and the COUNTIF function

I expect the output to show the colleague on a different sheet when his name is selected

Comment: Please note that stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Can you please show your code in your question and let us know exactly where you got stuck, so we can help you improve it?

Comment: Hi,Its okay i managed to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you have, post your solution as an answer to your own question. If anyone finds your question later, they will have the answer right away. This is how you help the community :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Dictionary will be your best choice. you may input Key as 'Bob' and restruction an Array to collect the data, after that Export Array into another worksheet.

Comment: it isnt just 1 name which i am attempting to pull out. Like the jobs completed will consist of 20 names maybe more as thre are a few technicians and not just the one. But i need to pull all the information which is on the technicians job